# how to set 5 record per page in xsl or xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Am using xml to generate the record and xsl to display the record in that i have 100 records and in that how to add page number.

How to set 5 record per page in xsl file or xml am try to use `<xsl:for-each select="main/sub">` but its give same record 5 times per page

```
<xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:for-each select="mani/sub">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="sub" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="./pages/page">
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="page" select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <p style="page-break-after: always"/> 
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="sub/sub">  i try this loop

Comment: <xsl:template match="book">
 <xsl:for-each select="mani/sub">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="sub" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="./pages/page">
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="page" select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <p style="page-break-after: always"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Comment: how  to set 5 record(page) per page

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML (perhaps with just 6 or 7 records) please? Also, can you show what you expect your output to look like in this case? Thank you!

Comment: <book> <number>B909</number><mani type="array"><sub><display-number>B909-1</display-number><pages type="array"><page><number>B0094</number><weight type="decimal">12</weight></page><page><number>B0094</number><weight type="decimal">20.50</weight></page><page><number>B0094</number><weight type="decimal">10</weight>
        </page>
        <page>
          <number>B0094</number>
          <weight type="decimal">90</weight>
        </page>
        <page>
          <number>B0094</number>
          <weight type="decimal">120</weight>
        </page>
      </pages>
    </sub>
  </mani>
</book>

Comment: B909  B909-1                                                                                                           B0094 12, B0095 20.50,                                                                                         <Page break>                                                                                                                  B909 B909-1                                                                                                                                           B0096 10, B0097 90,                               < page Break> B909 B909-1       B0098 120,

Comment: its my expect output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear about the structure of your output. However, putting one element in a for-each-loop after every n runs is pretty simple. You can do something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
     <xsl:template match="book">

     <xsl:for-each select="number|mani/sub/display-number|mani/sub/pages/page/number|mani/sub/pages/page/weight">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0"><Page_break/></xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This script takes all the numbers in your input, put each out, puts a whitespace after each. The crucial part is `position() mod 5 = 0`. This makes sure, that your page break element is only output if the current loop position is dividable by 5, which means: For every 5th run.

Btw: `<Page break>` is not well formed XML, you'd better change it to `<Page break>` or something like that.

Comment: In that how to added page number